# Access data in view Yii CSqlDataProvider and Relational Table

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm trying to join a relational table `profiles` at the `CSqlDataProvider`, but it's not working property.

How can I have access to `profiles.id` in the view?

Controller.php:

```
$sql = "SELECT `events`.`id`
        FROM events
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `profiles` ON (`events`.`profile_id`=`profiles`.`id`)";

$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql);
```

View.php:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'id'=>'events-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        'profiles.id', // Problem here, always returns NULL.
        'events.id',
    ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First ofcourse you need to `select` the other field as already mentioned in [Phillipe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14466506/720508) :

   ```
   SELECT `events`.`id`, `profiles`.`id` ...
   ```
2. It'll be better to give `profiles.id` an alias because the both the column names are `id`:

   ```
   SELECT `events`.`id`, `profiles`.`id` as pid ...
   ```
3. Then in the grid you can access these columns as:

   ```
   'columns'=>array(
       'pid', // instead of profiles.id
       'id', // instead of events.id
   )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your SQL query

```
$sql = "SELECT `events`.`id`, `profiles`.`id`
        FROM events
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `profiles` ON (`events`.`profile_id`=`profiles`.`id`)";
```

But you seem to already have profile.id in your events so you could just use this in your view:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'id'=>'events-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        'profile_id',
        'events.id',
    ),
)); ?>
```

Comment: If I use `events`.`profile_id` it works, but `profiles`.`id` do not work, always return NULL. I need to use related because I will user another fields besides id.

Comment: Can you only test this sql request in mysql ? phpMyadmin to show what is the result ?

Comment: The SQL is returning right data `events.id` and `profiles.id`. I think the problem is with TbGridView when trying to get `profiles.id`.

Comment: maybe this should help http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/